# How do i resolve this Uncaught runtime errors？

Tags: runtime

ERROR

[object Object] at handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:302:58) at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:325:7)

this is a vue question,please help me,thanks.
I want to run it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem when I implement the login function with vue.
So the problem is response interception function.
The wrong code:

```
service.interceptors.response.use((res)=>{
    const code:number = res.data.code
    if (code != 200) {
        return Promise.reject(res.data)
    }
    return res.data
},(err)=>{
    console.log(err);
})
```

The problem is `code` is in `res.data.data`.
And I modify it.

```
service.interceptors.response.use(({ data }) => {
    const code : number = data.data.code
    if(code != 200){
        return Promise.reject(data)
    }
    return data
},(err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Then I solve this error.